# Live Its Divsion

Tags: word-usage

I have a question about the usage of the verb "*live*" [here](http://online.wsj.com/articles/in-reunited-germany-one-town-remains-divided-1415342290):

> As the country celebrates its reunification this weekend, a tiny village divided by the Iron Curtain for four decades continues to ***live its division***, complete with wall, death strip and watchtowers.

Is "*live its division*" slightly nonstandard?  Would "*live its* **life of** *division*" be better?

Answer (score 1):

You could also say:

> As the country celebrates its reunification this weekend, a tiny village divided by the Iron Curtain for four decades continues to **live out** its division, complete with wall, death strip and watchtowers.

This usage is similar to:

> That was the way he decided to **live *out* his life**.
>   That was the way he decided to **live his life**.

Check the definition of [***live out***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/live+out):

> Verb   1.  live out - live out one's life; live to the end

Answer (score 0):

It's not non-standard to say "live its division". It's the same as you say "live a/its life of division. Please refer to The Free Dictionary under Thesaurus, where we find the following sentence:

"We had to live frugality after the war". I think it's also correct if we use the phrase "a life of frugality or a frugal life" instead.